# ¿Como puedo quitar una opcion de un Input type=range?

Tags: javascript, html, input-type

Estoy armando un sistema de prestamos, pero no quiero que la opción de cuota *10* salga en el *slider*. ¿Es posible eliminar esa opcion del **Slider**, y que las opciones de cuota solo sean de *2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11*?

```js
var slider1 = document.getElementById("mes");
var output1 = document.getElementById("mes1");
var output2 = document.getElementById("int");
let int = 0;
output1.innerHTML = slider1.value;
output2.innerHTML = int;

slider1.oninput = function() {
  output1.innerHTML = this.value;

  if (slider1.value == 2) {
    int = 3.18 + "%";
  }
  if (slider1.value == 3) {
    int = 4.55 + "%";
  }
  if (slider1.value == 4) {
    int = 5.82 + "%";
  }
  if (slider1.value == 5) {
    int = 6.66 + "%";
  }
  if (slider1.value == 6) {
    int = 7.61 + "%";
  }
  if (slider1.value == 7) {
    int = 8.52 + "%";
  }
  if (slider1.value == 8) {
    int = 9.59 + "%";
  }
  if (slider1.value == 9) {
    int = 10.64 + "%";
  }
  if (slider1.value == 10) {
    int = 11.95 + "%";
  }
  if (slider1.value == 11) {
    int = 13.10 + "%";
  }

  output2.innerHTML = int;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
      <h1>Lo quiero pagar en <span id="mes1"></span> cuotas <span><input type="range" class="inputDiv" name="mes" id="mes" min="2" max="11" step="1" value=1></span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="text-align: right;">
      <span>Interés Mensual: <span id="int"></span></span>
      <span><input type="hidden" name="interes"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Intente con var values:

```
var values = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11];
```

pero tampoco obtuve buenos resultados

Comment: puedes imprimir esos numeros  con js, y condificionar el input con un onchange, de si eligen el value 10 arroje un mensaje y setees el input range a 0

Comment: Deberias arreglar ese código que has puesto en el snippet. Quita todas las etiquetas `<script></script>` pues en el snippet no hacen falta y termina de poner la función `calcular()` pues no veo el cierre de la misma.

Comment: Si es verdad, lo subi a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/carlitosk/vqcr7dsj/3/
ahi esta funcionando correctamente! gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun veo lo del `var values` si que funciona, pero se tenia que afinar un poco más.

Aquí dejo un snippet funcional con los cambios realizados y si te va bien así paso a explicarlos cuando me lo confirmes (no todos son necesarios, pero me gusta más así):

```js
var slider1 = document.getElementById("mes");
var output1 = document.getElementById("mes1");
var output2 = document.getElementById("int");
let int = 0;

output1.innerHTML = slider1.value;
output2.innerHTML = int;

slider1.oninput = function() {
  values = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11];
  output1.innerHTML = values[this.value];
  value_cuota = (values[this.value])
  values_cuotas = {
    0: 0,
    2: 3.18,
    3: 4.55,
    4: 5.82,
    5: 6.66,
    6: 7.61,
    7: 8.52,
    8: 9.59,
    9: 10.64,
    10: 11.95,
    11: 13.10
  }

  int = values_cuotas[value_cuota] + "%";
  output2.innerHTML = int;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
        <h1>Lo quiero pagar en <span id="mes1"></span> cuotas <span><input type="range" class="inputDiv" name="mes" id="mes" min="0" max="9" step="1" value="0"></span></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: right;">
        <span>Interés Mensual: <span id="int"></span></span>
        <span><input type="hidden" name="interes"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Antes que nada, agradecerte toda tu ayuda!!! bien, ahora funciona perfecto que muestra la cuota 11, pero al elegir cuota 2 me da NaN, y tampoco deberia salir la opcion 0, ya que al presionar calcular tambien arroja NaN, que complicado! jaja

Comment: Super!! Lo Lograste!! solo falto agregar el values[mes]´para que el calculo de correcto!! te agradezco muchísimo!! voy a votar en tu solución! (ahora solo me queda quitar la opcion 0 o poner un mensaje para que no deje calcular si mes esta en 0)

Comment: Aquí te hago mi última aportación a tu problema con el 0:  https://jsfiddle.net/kgsu7pyc/  (basicamente deshabilito el boton de saque y despues lo habilito al mover el slider)  Saludos!